# Is it possible to bake a volume shader into vdb?

Tags: shaders

I made a cloud shader but I would like to export it as vdb. Is there any way to do this? It doesn't have any fluid simulation.

Comment: [Shader to OpenVDB](https://joshuabloemer.gumroad.com/l/export-openvdb) (Win only)